# FltRegisterFilter not working

Tags: c, windows, driver

I'm trying to create a simple windows driver, but the FltRegisterFilter is not working ! I got the following error code : 0xc0000034 (I think it refers to the STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND error code).

Do you know if the generated INF file is enough ? I just tried to add this line in a driver install section : Dependencies   = FltMgr.

Here is the full INF file :

```
;
; KmdfMiniFilter.inf
;

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Sample ; TODO: edit Class
ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171} ; TODO: edit ClassGuid
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=KmdfMiniFilter.cat
DriverVer=01/01/2017 ; TODO: set DriverVer in stampinf property pages

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12

; ================= Class section =====================

[ClassInstall32]
Addreg=SampleClassReg

[SampleClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-5

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]
KmdfMiniFilter.sys  = 1,,

;*****************************************
; Install Section
;*****************************************

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$

[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%KmdfMiniFilter.DeviceDesc%=KmdfMiniFilter_Device, Root\KmdfMiniFilter ; TODO: edit hw-id

[KmdfMiniFilter_Device.NT]
CopyFiles=Drivers_Dir

[Drivers_Dir]
KmdfMiniFilter.sys

;-------------- Service installation
[KmdfMiniFilter_Device.NT.Services]
AddService = KmdfMiniFilter,%SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE%, KmdfMiniFilter_Service_Inst

; -------------- KmdfMiniFilter driver install sections
[KmdfMiniFilter_Service_Inst]
DisplayName    = %KmdfMiniFilter.SVCDESC%
ServiceBinary  = %12%\KmdfMiniFilter.sys
ServiceType    = 1               ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 3               ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 1               ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
LoadOrderGroup = "FSFilter Activity Monitor"
Dependencies   = FltMgr

;
;--- KmdfMiniFilter_Device Coinstaller installation ------
;

[DestinationDirs]
KmdfMiniFilter_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles = 11

[KmdfMiniFilter_Device.NT.CoInstallers]
AddReg=KmdfMiniFilter_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg
CopyFiles=KmdfMiniFilter_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles

[KmdfMiniFilter_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000, "WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll,WdfCoInstaller"
HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance1.Flags%

[KmdfMiniFilter_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles]
WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll

[SourceDisksFiles]
WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll=1 ; make sure the number matches with SourceDisksNames

[KmdfMiniFilter_Device.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService =  KmdfMiniFilter, KmdfMiniFilter_wdfsect
[KmdfMiniFilter_wdfsect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = $KMDFVERSION$

[Strings]
SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE= 0x00000002
ManufacturerName="<Your manufacturer name>" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
ClassName="Samples" ; TODO: edit ClassName
DiskName = "KmdfMiniFilter Installation Disk"
KmdfMiniFilter.DeviceDesc = "KmdfMiniFilter Device"
KmdfMiniFilter.SVCDESC = "KmdfMiniFilter Service"

DefaultInstance         = "KmdfMiniFilter"
Instance1.Name          = "KmdfMiniFilter"
Instance1.Altitude      = "370120"
Instance1.Flags         = 0x0              ; Allow all attachments
```

Do you have any idea of what is the problem ?

Comment: I forgot to precise that I'm using Visual Studio 2015. And now the debug view print '\n' when it should print sentences... that's weird !

Comment: are you try simply use [DbgPrint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543632(v=vs.85).aspx) ? with `DbgView`. are macro `KdPrintEx` expanded to `DbgPrintEx` ?

Comment: I'm using the default debug view in Visual. No I didn't try DbgPrint but I will ! But that's very weird... when I create a file on my target machine, an empty line is printed in the debug view... so my callback function is called, and my KdPrintEx too... I suppose...

Comment: Thank you @RbMm but it was just a mistake :s So I edited my post to ask a new question !

Comment: are subkey `Instances\DefaultInstance` is created ? with `Altitude` - not view this in `inf`

Comment: something like this must be in inf - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/miniFilter/NameChanger/NameChanger.inf#L70

Comment: No they're not created... So I should add it in the [KmdfMiniFilter_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg] section? These two lines ? HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance% and 
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%

Comment: 3 lines - [72](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/miniFilter/NameChanger/NameChanger.inf#L72) too

Comment: Still not working... I check the registry on the target machine and I don't see the new one ! I don't understand the generated inf file... it's not like the one you gave me. For example, I don't find the hardware id (I have Root\KmdfMiniFilter in my generated file).

Comment: but MiniFilter must not have any hardware id. read [Creating an INF File for a Minifilter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/creating-an-inf-file-for-a-minifilter-driver)

Comment: Ah ! ok, I did that because of the following link, in the deployment configuration in Visual : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver

Comment: minifilter is not WDM driver. it have not any hardware id and another inf files. look for examples - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter for any inf here

Comment: take any `inf` from here as template. for example - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/miniFilter/change/change.inf#L61

Comment: I now have errors during the installation, where may I find the log files ? I didn't find anything in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp. Thank you for your answers by the way !

Comment: where is logs depended from how you install. exist different ways. can be for example in `\windows\DPINST.LOG`. look in windows folder `*.log` files, sort by modified time

Comment: Thank you @RbMm ! I fanally understood that I couldn't install the filter from visual... Now that I managed to install it from the target machine, I have a blue screen with the following code : IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL ! I'm close !

Comment: `IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL` well known code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problème thanks to RbMm !

A minifilter is not a WDM driver, so :

- it doesn't have any hardware id
- a good example of inf file : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/miniFilter/nullFilter/nullFilter.inf
- we can't install a minifilter from Visual Studio, so in Deployment settings, check "Not install". The files will be sent on the target machine. Then, go in you driver's folder (mine was : C:\DriverTest\Drivers). The sys file must be in the same directory than the inf file. Right-click on the inf file -> Install. And finally, open a prompt command (administrator), and use the following command to load and unload your filter : fltmc load myFilter.

Then, once your filter loaded, you must be able to debug it from Visual !