# The system cannot find the file specified - Mini Filter Driver

Tags: c++, driver

I am trying to develop a simple File System MiniFilter driver but I keep getting `System error2 has occured. The system cannot find the file specified`

My Inf File:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; companyName.INF -- NDIS LightWeight Filter Driver
;
; TODO: Search for comments marked "TODO:", and follow their instructions to
; customize this INF for your driver.  Then delete the "TODO:" comments.
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

[version]
; Do not change these values "NetService"
Signature       = "$Windows NT$"
Class           = NetService
ClassGUID       = {4D36E974-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
; TODO: Customize this string for your company name
Provider        = %Msft%
DriverVer       = 
CatalogFile     = companyName.cat


; TODO: Include each architecture for which your driver package contains a
; compiled binary.  If you do not supply a driver compiled for ia64, delete the
; NTia64 section.
[Manufacturer]
%Msft%=MSFT,NTx86,NTia64,NTamd64,NTarm,NTarm64

; MS_companyName can be used with netcfg.exe to install/uninstall the driver.
[MSFT.NTx86]
%companyName_Desc%=Install, MS_companyName

[MSFT.NTia64]
%companyName_Desc%=Install, MS_companyName

[MSFT.NTamd64]
%companyName_Desc%=Install, MS_companyName

[MSFT.NTarm]
%companyName_Desc%=Install, MS_companyName

[MSFT.NTarm64]
%companyName_Desc%=Install, MS_companyName

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Installation Section
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Install]
AddReg=Inst_Ndi
; All LWFs must include the 0x40000 bit (NCF_LW_FILTER). Unlike miniports, you
; don't usually need to customize this value.
Characteristics=0x40000

; This must be a random, unique value.
; FILTER_UNIQUE_NAME in filter.h must match this GUID identically.
; Both should have {curly braces}.
NetCfgInstanceId="{33e89230-1de5-44cf-959b-bba7ed0e72d1}"

Copyfiles = companyName.copyfiles.sys

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%companyName_Desc%,"",,

[SourceDisksFiles]
; TODO: Include any related files that should be installed with your driver.
companyName.sys=1

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12
companyName.copyfiles.sys=12

[companyName.copyfiles.sys]
companyName.sys,,,2


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Ndi installation support
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Inst_Ndi]
HKR, Ndi,Service,,"companyName"
HKR, Ndi,CoServices,0x00010000,"companyName"
HKR, Ndi,HelpText,,%companyName_HelpText%
; TODO: Set the FilterClass here.  The FilterClass controls the order in which
; filters are bound to the underlying miniport.  Possible options include:
;     Custom, Diagnostic, Failover, Loadbalance, Vpn, Compression, Encryption, Scheduler
; See MSDN for a description of each.
HKR, Ndi,FilterClass,, compression
; TODO: Specify whether you have a Modifying or Monitoring filter.
; For a Monitoring filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 1 ; Monitoring filter
; For a Modifying filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 2 ; Modifying filter
HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001,2
; Do not change these values
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,UpperRange,,"noupper"
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange,,"nolower"
; TODO: Ensure that the list of media types below is correct.  Typically,
; filters include "ethernet".  Filters may also include "ppip" to include
; native WWAN stacks, but you must be prepared to handle the packet framing.
; Possible values are listed on MSDN, but common values include:
;     ethernet, wan, ppip, wlan
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, FilterMediaTypes,,"ethernet, wan, ppip"
; TODO: Specify whether you have a Mandatory or Optional filter.
; For a Mandatory filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 1 ; Mandatory filter
; For an Optional filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 2 ; Optional filter
HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 1 ; Mandatory filter

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Service installation support
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Install.Services]
; TODO: You may want to add the SPSVCINST_STARTSERVICE flag, like this:
;     AddService=companyName,0x800,companyName_Service_Inst ; SPSVCINST_STARTSERVICE
AddService=companyName,,companyName_Service_Inst

[companyName_Service_Inst]
DisplayName     = %companyName_Desc%
ServiceType     = 1 ;SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
; Typically you will want your filter driver to start with SERVICE_SYSTEM_START.
; If it is an Optional filter, you may also use 3;SERVICE_DEMAND_START.
StartType       = 1 ;SERVICE_SYSTEM_START
ErrorControl    = 1 ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary   = %12%\companyName.sys
LoadOrderGroup  = companyName
Description     = %companyName_Desc%
AddReg          = Common.Params.reg, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions.reg

[Install.Remove.Services]
; The SPSVCINST_STOPSERVICE flag instructs SCM to stop the NT service
; before uninstalling the driver.
DelService=companyName,0x200 ; SPSVCINST_STOPSERVICE

[Common.Params.reg]
; TODO: You can add any sort of NDIS parameters here.  Filter drivers
; don't always need NDIS parameters, so it's okay to have nothing here.

; TODO: Remove the sample parameters below.

; Sample 1: "DriverParam" is a per-driver parameter.
HKR, FilterDriverParams\DriverParam,     ParamDesc,   , "Driverparam for lwf"
HKR, FilterDriverParams\DriverParam,     default,     , "5"
HKR, FilterDriverParams\DriverParam,     type,        , "int"

; Sample 2: "AdapterParam" is a per-module parameter.
HKR, FilterAdapterParams\AdapterParam,   ParamDesc,   , "Adapterparam for lwf"
HKR, FilterAdapterParams\AdapterParam,   default,     , "10"
HKR, FilterAdapterParams\AdapterParam,   type,        , "int"

[NdisImPlatformBindingOptions.reg]
; By default, when an LBFO team or Bridge is created, all filters will be
; unbound from the underlying members and bound to the TNic(s). This keyword
; allows a component to opt out of the default behavior
; To prevent binding this filter to the TNic(s):
;   HKR, Parameters, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions,0x00010001,1 ; Do not bind to TNic
; To prevent unbinding this filter from underlying members:
;   HKR, Parameters, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions,0x00010001,2 ; Do not unbind from Members
; To prevent both binding to TNic and unbinding from members:
;   HKR, Parameters, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions,0x00010001,3 ; Do not bind to TNic or unbind from Members
HKR, Parameters, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions,0x00010001,0 ; Subscribe to default behavior



[Strings]
; TODO: Customize these strings.
Msft = "companyName" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
companyName_Desc = "companyName Driver Test"
companyName_HelpText = "companyName Driver Test"
```

C++ Code:

```
/*++

Copyright (c) 1999 - 2002  Microsoft Corporation

Module Name:

    SwapBuffers.c

Abstract:

    This is a sample filter which demonstrates proper access of data buffer
    and a general guideline of how to swap buffers.
    For now it only swaps buffers for:

    IRP_MJ_READ
    IRP_MJ_WRITE
    IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL

    By default this filter attaches to all volumes it is notified about.  It
    does support having multiple instances on a given volume.

Environment:

    Kernel mode

--*/

#include <fltKernel.h>
#include <dontuse.h>
#include <suppress.h>


PFLT_FILTER FilterHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags);
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS flags);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext);


const FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
    {IRP_MJ_CREATE,0,MiniPreCreate,MiniPostCreate},
    {IRP_MJ_WRITE,0,MiniPreCreate,NULL},
    {IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END}
};
const FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {
    sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,
    0,
    NULL,
    Callbacks,
    MiniUnload,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};
NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags) {
    KdPrint(("driver unload \r\n"));
    FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS flags) {
    KdPrint(("Post Create is running \r\n"));
    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[300] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260) {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);
                KdPrint(("CreateFile: %ws \r\n", Name));
            }
        }
        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContext) {
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[300] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260) {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);
                _wcsupr(Name);
                if (wcsstr(Name, L"OPENME.TXT") != NULL) {
                    KdPrint(("Write File: %ws Blocked \r\n", Name));
                    Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                    Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
                    return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
                }
                KdPrint(("CreateFile: %ws \r\n", Name));
            }
        }
        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}


NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    NTSTATUS status;

    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &FilterHandle);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        status = FltStartFiltering(FilterHandle);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

I tried many options suggest on the web such as:

1. Using SC Create to create the service
2. Confirming that system32\drivers\companyName.sys file exist
3. BCDedit to disable signature signing security or using advanced boot mode
   and etc.

When I try to run `net start companyname` I get:

```
System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I couldn't find my service (companyName) under service but I do see it exist in registry at: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\companyName`

ImagePath value:
\??\C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Debug\companyName.sys
I also changed this to C:\windows\system32\drivers\companyName.sys but neither worked.

I mainly use OSRLoader to register and load driver, but that in this case failed as well.

I am wondering if there is something wrong with my INF file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Run procmon to see what non-existent file is trying to be accessed.

Comment: @Luke looking at the event logs, I see the following warning `File System Filter 'companyname' (Version 10.0, ‎2022‎-‎06‎-‎06T19:54:50.000000000Z) failed to register with Filter Manager.  The final status for this operation was 0xC0000034.`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. I solved it by installing my Mini Filter driver (by right-clicking on the .inf file and then clicking 'Install' option) on the Test machine. After that, running `fltmc load myFilter` in cmd on the Test machine to start the Filter driver.

Using `svc` gave me the same error as you.

I referred to this answer: [FltRegisterFilter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389211/fltregisterfilter-not-working)